# Estoy haciendo una pagina de music y quiero que mi buscador encuentre las canciones del archivo json y que la canción encontrada suene al darle click

Tags: javascript, html, json

**mi archivo Json**

```
{
    "songs": [{
            "name": "vive",
            "song": "music/uno.mp3",
            "reproducciones": 10,
            "image": "img/icon_4.svg"
        },
        {
            "name": "invierno",
            "song": "music/dos.mp3",
            "reproducciones": 30,
            "image": "img/icon_1.svg"
        },
        {
            "name": "planeta",
            "song": "music/tres.mp3",
            "reproducciones": 20,
            "image": "img/icon_3.svg"
        },
        {
            "name": "suave",
            "song": "music/cuatro.mp3",
            "reproducciones": 80,
            "image": "img/icon_2.svg"
        },
        {
            "name": "contigo",
            "song": "music/cinco.mp3",
            "reproducciones": 50,
            "image": "img/icon_4.svg"
        },
        {
            "name": "alas",
            "song": "music/seis.mp3",
            "reproducciones": 70,
            "image": "img/icon_1.svg"
        },
        {
            "name": "verde",
            "song": "music/siete.mp3",
            "reproducciones": 60,
            "image": "img/icon_3.svg"
        },
        {
            "name": "nuevamente",
            "song": "music/ocho.mp3",
            "reproducciones": 90,
            "image": "img/icon_1.svg"
        },
        {
            "name": "hoy",
            "song": "music/nueve.mp3",
            "reproducciones": 40,
            "image": "img/icon_2.svg"
        }
    ] }
```

**mi archivo html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reproductor.css">

    <title>OYE-CANCIONES</title> </head>

<body>
    <!--Barra de Navegación-->
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
            <div class="container-fluid">

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.png">OYE</a>

                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#barra" aria-controls="barra" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="barra">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Inicio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="canciones.html">Canciones</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- Ventana Modal -->
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#miModal">Contacto</button>
                    <div id="miModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <!-- Contenido del modal -->
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <h3>Contactanos en OYE</h3>
                                    <p>Correo Electrónico: <em>oyemimusic@correooye.com</em></p>
                                    <p>Teléfono: <em>+57 3218423955</em></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="login.html">Registro</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="registro.html">Login</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <!--Seccion de container-->
    <div class="container content-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                <h3>Canciones</h3>
                <img src="img/logo-2.png" alt="">
                <form action="" class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control my-2" id="formulario" placeholder="Escriba aquí su canción">
                </form>
                <div class="col-md-6 content-flex">
                    <ul class="list-group list-inline" id="playlist">
                    </ul>
                    <div id="resultado"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-flex mt-4">
        <div class="row row-cols-3 g-2">
            <div class="col-4 mt-1">
                <div class="p-3 border bg-light">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <img class="img-fluid" id="img-album" src="img/icon_4.svg" width="300" alt="">
                            <h6>vive</h6>
                            <audio id="player" controls=""></audio>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 mt-1">
                <div class="p-3 border bg-light">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <img class="img-fluid" id="img-album" src="img/icon_1.svg" width="300" alt="">
                            <h6>invierno</h6>
                            <audio id="player" controls=""></audio>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 mt-1">
                <div class="p-3 border bg-light">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <img class="img-fluid" id="img-album" src="img/icon_3.svg" width="300" alt="">
                            <h6>planeta</h6>
                            <audio id="player" controls=""></audio>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 mt-1">
                <div class="p-3 border bg-light">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <img class="img-fluid" id="img-album" src="img/icon_2.svg" width="300" alt="">
                            <h6>suave</h6>
                            <audio id="player" controls=""></audio>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 mt-1">
                <div class="p-3 border bg-light">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <img class="img-fluid" id="img-album" src="img/icon_4.svg" width="300" alt="">
                            <h6>contigo</h6>
                            <audio id="player" controls=""></audio>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 mt-1">
                <div class="p-3 border bg-light">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <img class="img-fluid" id="img-album" src="img/icon_1.svg" width="300" alt="">
                            <h6>alas</h6>
                            <audio id="player" controls=""></audio>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 mt-1">
                <div class="p-3 border bg-light">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <img class="img-fluid" id="img-album" src="img/icon_3.svg" width="300" alt="">
                            <h6>verde</h6>
                            <audio id="player" controls=""></audio>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 mt-1">
                <div class="p-3 border bg-light">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <img class="img-fluid" id="img-album" src="img/icon_1.svg" width="300" alt="">
                            <h6>nuevamente</h6>
                            <audio id="player" controls=""></audio>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 mt-1">
                <div class="p-3 border bg-light">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <img class="img-fluid" id="img-album" src="img/icon_2.svg" width="300" alt="">
                            <h6>hoy</h6>
                            <audio id="player" controls=""></audio>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="container-fluid py-1 bg-danger text-white">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col text-left ">
                Comparte la música</em>
            </div>
            <div class="col text-right ">
                &copy;Derechos Reservados</em>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/reproductor.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

**Mi archivo javaScript**

```
/* Buscador*/ /*jshint esversion: 6 */ 

const canciones = [
    { nombre: 'Vive' },
    { nombre: 'Invierno' },
    { nombre: 'Planeta' },
    { nombre: 'Suave' },
    { nombre: 'Contigo' },
    { nombre: 'Alas' },
    { nombre: 'Verde' },
    { nombre: 'Nuevamente' },
    { nombre: 'Hoy' }, ]; const formulario = document.querySelector('#formulario');

const filtrar = () => {
    resultado.innerHTML = '';


    const texto = formulario.value.toLowerCase();
    for (let cancion of canciones) {
        let nombre = cancion.nombre.toLowerCase();
        if (nombre.indexOf(texto) !== -1) {
            resultado.innerHTML += `            <li> ${cancion.nombre} </li>
            `;
        }
    }
    if (resultado.innerHTML === '') {
        resultado.innerHTML += `            <li>Canción no encontrada...</li>       `;
    } };

formulario.addEventListener('keyup', filtrar);

$(document).ready(function() {
    getSongs(); }); var audio = document.getElementById('player'); var music;

function getSongs() {
    $.getJSON("js/datos.json", function(mjson) {
        music = mjson;
        genList(music);
    }); }

function playSong(id) {
    console.log(id);
    var long = music.songs;
    if (id >= long.length) {
        console.log('Se acabó');
        audio.pause();
    } else {
        $('#img-album').attr('src', music.songs[id].image);
        $('#player').attr('src', music.songs[id].song);
        audio.play();
        console.log('Hay mas canciones');
        scheduleSong(id);
    }

}

function genList(music) {
    console.log(music.songs);
    $.each(music.songs, function(i, song) {
        $('#playlist').append('<li class="list-group-item" id="' + i + '">' + song.name + '</li>');
    });
    $('#playlist li').click(function() {
        var selectedsong = $(this).attr('id');
        playSong(selectedsong);
    }); }

function scheduleSong(id) {
    audio.onended = function() {
        console.log('Terminó la canción');
        playSong(parseInt(id) + 1);
    }; }`
```

Comment: Muy bonito tu código pero... te faltó describir el problema que tienes :). Por favor lee [ask] y de paso haces es [tour] y ganas tu primera medalla!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Tengo unas canciones cargadas en un archivo Json,  para poderlas escuchar en la website hice un JavaScript que me permite leer estas canciones y reproducirlas, lo que yo quiero es añadir un buscador, u filtro de búsqueda,  en el website para que cuando yo busque la canción me la muestre y poder darle clic encima para que se reproduzca. El código que muestro arriba le falta el filtro de búsqueda que no he podido solucionar.